# MySQL php select statement using WAMP server

Tags: php, html, mysql, wamp

Im trying to display a database table in my html page but cant seem to get it to work. (code below):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1> Table </h1>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "Library";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `books` ORDER BY `Category` ASC ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<br> id: ". $row["ISBN"]. " Name: ". $row["firstname"]. " - Author: " . $row["BookAuthor"]. " Category: " . $row["Category"]. " - Quantity: " . $row["Quantity"]. " - Price: " . $row["Price"]. "<br>";
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Im using WAMP server and the "books" table is located in a database called Library. However the table doesnt display and all i get is the php code being shown.

Any idea on whats gone wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: is the file with .php extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Is your WAMP running? (Check the system tray icon. It should be green)
2. Did you mess with PHP or Apache configs?
3. Is the file extension .php? It has to be.
4. Is other PHP displaying properly?

Comment: Ah noob mistake.. forgot the .php extension haha

Comment: Everyone makes mistakes sometimes. :)
If this solved the problem, please mark the answer as correct.